# Auto adjusting image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a slider like the one found at: http://designmodo.com/startup/

Our website currently uses bootstrap 2 so i am using the default carousel as a template.
I want the image slider to automatically size to fit the screen height, so the slider will always be 100% of the height of the display.

I was hoping someone could help me out with this, the current slider can be found at http://temp.tefl.org.uk/ and the code for it so far can be seen below:

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 </ol>

<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="active item"><img src="/media/377330/c79211ae4c84c8a692f278f1d2aeeda0.png" style="width:100%"/></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="/media/377337/b91313eb7c28be9bfea650edef5ac425.png" style="width:100%"/></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="/media/377344/34aa259a765d17cc20af80a7a14038ba.png" style="width:100%"/></div>
</div>

<!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code in `window.load` function and use it as global variables. 
   You can compare the window dimensions with the image by storing the initial dimensions of the image in the global variables.

```
var imgH = $('#top-slider .carousel-inner').height();
var imgW = $('#top-slider .carousel-inner').width();
```